# Wsdl to Spring Ws

Tags: spring, web-services, jax-ws, jaxb2

Does it exist a method to generate a Spring Ws Soap Stub from WSDL file  with bean type and method of port ?

I can generate all stub (Bean Type and Method) with Jaxws from WSDL instead with Jaxb I can generate from my wsdl only Object Type.

My Ide is IntelliJ 14.

Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring WS doesn't provide any utility
In any case you can use JAXB or JAX-WS integrated with spring ws
Some usefull links:

- [Spring WS + JAX-WS](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/)
- [Spring WS + JAXB (see consuming SOAP)](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)